# Scale Image View with Bottom center as pivot point

Tags: android

Currently, I am using the following XML file to animate an `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator">
       <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="1.0"
        android:pivotY="1.5"

        android:duration="500"></scale>
</set>
```

But the scale starts at top-left corner. I want to start the scale at the bottom-center. I played around some of its values but still I could not achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these values

```
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"

    android:duration="500"></scale>
```

Comment: Use the `RELATIVE_TO_SELF` type with current pivot values.. Pivot values will be multiplied with the view height and width to determine the pivot point.,